# Custom "New Contact" button on Account detail page

Tags: custom-button

I've a created a custom button on Contact object and added this to Contact Related-list on Account's Page layout. I want this to depict same functionality as standard "New Contact" button does. If use following code then it doesn't pre-populate the Account lookup field.

```
{!$Action.Contact.New}
```

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
window.open('{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.NewContact, Contact.Id )}');
```

Update : try this : click on inspect element on the lookup button and you can find Id of the lookup as con4_lkwgt (I would assume this to be same since its a standard field) and click on the account name field and get the ID as con4

```
/003/e?con4={!Account.Name}&con4_lkwgt={!Account.Id}&&retURL=/{!Account.Id}
```

Refer this blog for more insight on how to override the buttons 
http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html

Comment: have you tried above thing?

Comment: ah i am sorry I actually was working on this never knew i posted,I will try to post ans shortly

Comment: try this : create a button with URL : /003/e?con4={!Account.Name}&con4_lkwgt={!Account.Id}&&retURL=/{!Account.Id} the con4 corresponds to the account name and th con4_lkwgt corresponds to the lookup!! I tried and was able to create a record with account prepopulated :)

Comment: thanks @rao. Will it also work for custom object? If we have same scenario but instead of contact we have custom object which has a lookup to account object.

Comment: yes it will look at the comment I posted in eyescreams post :)

Comment: All you need to do is pass the value of account as a param to the URL. you can easily get the id of the field by using chrome. right click on the account lookup icon and say inspect element and it will show the id of the corresponding form element in a window below.

Comment: @rao - minor thing. Form prepopulation is done by `name` attribute of `<input>` etc, not by `id`. Luckily we're quite safe in SF world but you know, in case you ever need to craft an URL to other system... Run this one and you'll see: translate.google.com/?source=id_works&text=no,name_works_better :)

Comment: @eyescream point noted. I always have used ids for passing values and never knew name mattered more than id!!! how do you maintain uniqness?? what if there are 2 form elements with same name?? I know id has uniqueness validator so just curious

Comment: @rao It's been a while since I wrote HTML forms by hand... If I recall correctly duplicate `name`s mean last value will "win" so it will be overwritten in the order in which they appear in form. There's one exception: `name="myVariable[]"` with brackets. It's used if you want to pass multiple values to the server (think "3 out of 5 checkboxes ticked" or `<select>` tag with multiple options (ctrl+click)). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631224/getting-multiple-checkboxes-names-ids-with-php

Comment: @eyescream point noted. I always have used ids for passing values and never knew name mattered more than id!!! how do you maintain uniqness?? what if there are 2 form elements with same name?? I know id has uniqueness validator so just curious

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to look at the field names. The list of names for standard fields is for example here: http://phollaio.tumblr.com/post/22058016777/how-to-obtain-a-field-id, for custom fields it's usually the field Id when viewed in setup (in case of doubt use Firebug or similar tool to inspect the HTML).

Something like this should give you the general idea how to start:

```
/003/e?con4_lkid={!Account.Id}&name_firstcon2=Hello&name_lastcon2=StackOverflow
```

It's up to you if you want to write full URL yourself or do you prefer to read a bit more about `URLFOR` function (quite powerful). Generally speaking this will populate Account nicely if you've fired it from rel. list under Account - from other places it is likely to return empty string so you might have to use `CASE()` or similar to make it more generic (depends on when do you plan to use the button).

Comment: if I have custom object instead of Contact object which is also having lookup to Account then it will also work?

Comment: doga it does but in the con4_lkid replace it with the corresponding field Id for account lookup on the custom object where the account lookup is created