# how to STOP salesforce standard AUTOPOPULATION of fields

Tags: standard-objects

Is there any way by which we can STOP STANDARD AUTOPOPULATION of fields
Eg:

When i click New Contact from Accounts Related list,Contacts Phone and fax field get autopopulated with Accouns phone and Fax value..

Comment: Can you provide an example of where this is happening that you want to stop?

Comment: Yes sure.. When i click New Contact from Accounts Related list,Contacts Phone and fax field get autopopulated with Accouns phone and Fax value..

Comment: I solved my issue: I Created acustom button with URL "/003/e?con4={!Account.Name}&con10=&con11="

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the <kbd>New Contact</kbd> button from the **Account** page, Salesforce auto links the contact to that account and pre-fills some fields for our convenience. if you want to avoid this, you might need to use a custom URL button which opens a New Contact page without any fields being populated.

You can refer this [previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4581/custom-new-contact-button-on-account-detail-page) on how to do this.